# Erlang jsx:encode remove escape backslash

Tags: json, erlang, encode, jsx

I'm calling a Api Service that has the following json requirement:

```
    {
       "user": {
         "userid": "123456"  
       },
      "access_token": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMPNOPQRST"
    }
```

I'm doing the following in my code:

```
   MyUser =  {<<"uid">>, <<"MyId-1">>},
   Body = json_body_([{{<<"user">>, MyUser},{<<"access_token">>, <<?ORGANIZATION_ACCESS_TOKEN>>}}]),
   Body1 = lists:map(fun erlang:tuple_to_list/1, Body), 
   io:format("Body in start : ~n~p~n", [Body1]).

    json_body_(ParamList) ->
        json_body__(ParamList, []).

    json_body__([], Acc) ->
        jsx:encode(lists:reverse(Acc));
    json_body__([{K, V} | Rest], Acc) ->
        Acc1 = [{sanitize_(K), sanitize_(V)} | Acc],
    json_body__(Rest, Acc1).
    sanitize_(Parm) ->
        Parm.
```

When I apply jsx:enocode to "Body1" the result is:

```
    [{\"user\":{\"uid\":\"My-id-1234\"},\"access_token\":\"12345678ff4089\"}]
```

How can I get rid of the escape "\"?

Comment: Is that the exact output of that `io:format` line?

Comment: I've edited the io:format result. is there any way I can get rid of escape "\".

Comment: What do you get if you print with the format string `"~s~n"`?

Comment: I've tried format string also. I've noticed it is getting rid of the escapes "\". How do I feed the result as input to my function.

Comment: The `\\` is the result of printing the value. You should not need to alter the value to use the backslash-less representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string doesn't contain any `\`. Since you printed using `~p`, Erlang escaped every double quote in the string to make the final output valid Erlang code. You can verify this by printing using `~s` instead.

```
1> S = "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}".
"{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"
2> io:format("~p~n", [S]).
"{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"
ok
3> io:format("~s~n", [S]).
{"foo": "bar"}
ok
```

Comment: Sorry, for my late reply...yes it was a formatting issue. I've rectified my code. Thanks.